# The pictures of shivling present in Gyanvapi Kashi

Tags: shiva

The leaked pictures of shivling were found in gyanvapi Kashi, I hope at least some people here have seen it.

To those who have seen those, why does the shivling have a round bar like shape protruding outside from the center, is the bar like shape drilled afterward by other people to make it not look like shivling?

The main purpose of this question is to know the shape of Shivling.

Comment: Skanda Purana, Kashi khanda has the details.